# Iterate over two loops (CURSOR and WHILE) and print the records grouped by location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to print the records grouped by each location (in this case they are 2), duly ordered.

I'm testing with a cursor but it prints the same location twice.

How can I fix this?

```
    DECLARE @DateMovementsTopWorst AS DATE;
    DECLARE @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst AS NUMERIC;
    DECLARE @FamilyTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @BufferTopWorst AS NUMERIC;
    DECLARE @SkuTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @LocationTopWorst AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @Counter3 AS INT = 1;
    DECLARE @Location AS VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @Temporal2 AS INT = 10;
    DECLARE ExternCursor CURSOR
        FOR SELECT DISTINCT(LOCATION) FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER

    OPEN ExternCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor INTO @Location;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    --WHILE @Counter3 <  @Temporal+1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counter2 AS INT = 1;
        --SET ROWCOUNT @Counter3;
        PRINT ' SKU: '
            + '     Size: '
            + '     Family: '
            + '     Inventory: '
            + '     Movement Date: '

        WHILE @Counter2 < 6
        BEGIN
            SET ROWCOUNT @Counter2;

                SELECT @SkuTopWorst= SKU,
                    @BufferTopWorst= BUFFER,
                    @FamilyTopWorst = FAMILY,
                    @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst = TOTAL_INVENTORY_ON_SITE,
                    @DateMovementsTopWorst = UPDATE_MOVEMENTS,
                    @LocationTopWorst = LOCATION,
                    @Temporal2 = COUNT(*) OVER ()
                FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER
                WHERE LOCATION = @Location
                ORDER BY TOTAL_INVENTORY_ON_SITE ASC;
                PRINT @SkuTopWorst
                    + ' '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @BufferTopWorst)
                    + '     '
                    +  @FamilyTopWorst
                    + '         '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @InventoryOnSiteTopWorst)
                    + '         '
                    +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @DateMovementsTopWorst);
                SET @Counter2 = @Counter2+1;
        END
        PRINT 'This is: ' + @Location;
        --SET @Counter3 = @Counter3+1;
        FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor;
    END
    CLOSE ExternCursor
    DEALLOCATE ExternCursor
```

[image: Results]

Edited with suggestions from users. But we have the same results

Comment: I suggest creating a temp table of test table and adding it to your question so someone can test the code.

Comment: Please ensure you provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the cursor data for anything - therefore you inner query gets all your locations. You need to obtain the value from the cursor and then use it to filter your inner query. The following changes are required:

1. Add `DECLARE @Location AS VARCHAR(50);` near the start.
2. Modify your `fetch`'s to be `FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor INTO @Location;`
3. Modify your inner `where` to be `WHERE [LOCATION] = @Location`

Answer (score 1):

In the WHILE loop you have the SQL with this statement:

```
WHERE LOCATION IN (SELECT DISTINCT(LOCATION)
                     FROM TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER)
```

So the WHILE loop get all the location,
you need to change both:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor;
```

into

```
FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor INTO @location;
```

and then the WHERE statement in

```
WHERE LOCATION = @location
```

So for each Distinct location in TFSCM_CLI_BUFFER the WHILE loop will take care of one at a time.

P.S. Declare @location with the other var before the cursor.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't add comment to other answers. Have you tried in the WHILE to print @location? Has it is Distinct you should get two different values. If not, just as a try, instead of SELECT DISTINC use SELECT LOCATION FROM TABLE GROUP BY LOCATION....

Comment: Got that I think, mine and @Dale K answers are right... you forgot to change the FETCH NEXT FROM ExternCursor; into the cursor, so it doesn't fetch the second location.